# Integer arrays to accommodate several 64 bit long integers to compose the big integer

Tags: python

You know that the maximum size of integers modern machines can accommodate islimited to 64 bits in unsigned long form. Implement a method that can add two 1024 bit unsignedbig integer numbers. Remember to construct an abstract data type (ADT) in the form of a class orobject or structure as MyBigInteger. The prototype of your addition method should bedef add(a: MyBigInteger, b:MyBigInteger)(10 marts)Hint: Use integer arrays to accommodate several 64 bit long integers to compose the big integer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Integers in Python are of arbitrary size. Why is this tagged for Python?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind your homework question is to create a data type that can store 1024 bits. You can do this by creating a class with a class variable that is an array of 16 64-bit ints, as 16 * 64 = 1024.

If you understand base notation you can think of each array index as a digit in a number that is base 2^64.  If not, search up the concept of base notation. Or you can think of this resulting data structure as essentially putting 16 segments of 64 bits next to each other, creating a large segment of 1024 bits that can store numbers from 0 to 2^1024 - 1.

So when you add two the objects created from this BigInteger class simply go by the rules of place value.